# Integral operator does not compile

Tags: fonts, symbols, lyx

When I put `\int` on LyX it doesn't compile. I had tried to refresh and update and nothing works. It throws me this error:

> ```
> Font\U/esint/m/n/12=esint10 at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
> Font\U/esint/m/n/8=esint10 at 8pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
> Font\U/esint/m/n/6=esint10 at 6pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
> \textfont6 is undefined (character 1).
> \textfont6 is undefined (character 1).
> \textfont6 is undefined (character 1).
> \textfont6 is undefined (character 1).
> ```

Please I need help! I need to finish my homework today :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Could you give so called MWE (minimal, complete source code, showing your problem)? In particular, `esint` is rather mysterious.

Comment: Yes, please give a MWE. Do you happen to be using Windows and MikTeX (this info is also always good to give in posts)? If so, it sounds like you're having a similar problem as what was reported [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-docs@lists.lyx.org/msg07741.html). The person was unable to solve his problem, but maybe the proposed solutions would work for you.